# Youtube subscript user using API

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube, youtube-api

I am planning to create page where there will be one youtube subscribe button.
As user click on that button the youtube channel (Which I have provided in code) subscrib request send to youtube and user should subscribed.

If user is not logged in GMail then it should auto handle authentication process and then subscription and return to source page.

Can anyone tell me how can I achive this!?

[I have gone througn this](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions/insert) but it not help me.

Comment: Why so much effort wouldn't a static button do for you?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js"></script>

<script>
function onYtEvent(payload) {
if (payload.eventType == 'subscribe') {
  // Add code to handle subscribe event.
} else if (payload.eventType == 'unsubscribe') {
  // Add code to handle unsubscribe event.
}
if (window.console) { // for debugging only
  window.console.log('YT event: ', payload);
}
}
</script>

<div class="g-ytsubscribe" data-channel="nawarajshah" data-layout="default" data-count="default" data-onytevent="onYtEvent"></div>
```

Add this code on your website, then replace "nawarajshah" with your Youtube Channel.